# Unable to block element Adguard content blocker

Tags: browser, content-filter

I am using AdGuard Content Blocker with Samsung Internet on Android. I want to block an element (top ad banner) on [livemint.com](https://livemint.com)

After inspecting element, I found these div tags.

> `<div id="adfreeDivMobile" class="mobileAd">`
>
> > `<div class="adHolder adHolderTop" id="pushDownAd">`

I followed this AdGuard [guide](https://kb.adguard.com/en/general/how-to-create-your-own-ad-filters#example-cosmetic-rule-1)

In AdGuard user rule I wrote `livemint.com###adfreeDivMobile`
but it doesn't work :/

Comment: Livemint.com is delivered via SSL.  Did you install AdGuard's SSL certificate?  Is Samsung Internet compatible with it, or does Samsung use their own certificate repository?

Comment: If you are open to switching web browser, you can install Firefox for Android and its addon Ublock Origin (UBO). UBO is a content blocker which very easily can block what you are trying to.

Comment: @RockPaperLz-MaskitorCasket

The ad isn't displayed on the top banner but that area is still visible and that's not being blocked using cosmetic rule as mentioned in main post. I tried over-writing CSS rule it too doesn't work. Any workaround?

In inspect, I tried changing property of class="mobileAd"

    `livemint.com#$#.mobileAd {display: none!important; }`

Comment: @Firelord AdGuard is compatible with Firefox.  No need for uBlock Origin if Karl has AdGuard.

Comment: Karl, it looks like you are doing everything correct, but you probably need to have that SSL certificate installed and working in the browser you are using.  Likely, the ad itself is blocked by either DNS or URL filters, but the CSS is not getting injected for some reason.  To test, you can disable all the DNS and URL filters and keep the CSS filters.  If the ad re-appears, you'll know for sure.

Comment: @rockpaperlz Yeah, I performed checks by several methods. And it seems it is browser specific problem. How can I install SSL certificate or it's browser side issue.

Comment: IIRC, Samsung Internet browser is a bit of an anomaly.  I don't recall which SSL certificates it uses.  In AdGuard for Android, you go to Settings -> Network -> HTTPS Filtering to install its SSL certificate.  You'll be given the choice to install one globally for Android or specifically for Firefox (Firefox uses its own certificate store for improved security).